# Unable to update google sheet value of a cell using google spreadsheet api v4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, google-sheets-api

I am unable to update the sheets row value of a particular cells. I am using google api v4.0 and google spreadsheet npm package. I am getting an error using it in discord bot js. The error is

> (node:5956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: rows2[i].save
> is not a function
> at checkStatus (D:\discortbot\src\bot.js:95:30)

My code is as follows:

```
 sheet3 = doc2.sheetsByIndex[sheetIndex]; // Data from back which I have checked is coming correctly!
                   var rows2 = await sheet3.getRows({
                });  
                rows2 = rows2.map(a=>a._rawData);
                var size = rows2.length;
               
                for(var i=0;i<size;i++){
                   if(rows2[i][0]==email){
                    rows2[i].candidateID = userID;
                    rows2[i].RoleID =  sheetarr[2];
                     //rows2[i].save(); This one is also not working
                    console.log(rows2[i].candidateID); // Values are printing in console
                    console.log(rows2[i].RoleID); // Values are  printing in console
                    await rows2[i].save(); // Error giving me
                    verified = 1;
                    break;
                   } 
                    
                }
                if(verified==1){
                    message.author.send("Your account has been verified.Welcome to Outscal batch!");
                }else{

                }
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error? Kindly help me in solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please confirm the variables you want to use, again.

```
var sheet3 = doc2.sheetsByIndex[sheetIndex];
var rows2 = await sheet3.getRows();
// rows2 = rows2.map(a=>a._rawData);  // Removed
var size = rows2.length;

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  if (rows2[i]._rawData[0] == email) {  // Modified
    rows2[i].candidateID = userID;
    rows2[i].RoleID = sheetarr[2];
    console.log(rows2[i].candidateID); // Values are printing in console
    console.log(rows2[i].RoleID); // Values are  printing in console
    await rows2[i].save();
    verified = 1;
    break;
  }
}
if (verified == 1) {
  message.author.send("Your account has been verified.Welcome to Outscal batch!");
} else {
}
```

#### Reference:

- [node-google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet)